# How to assign in nested object using Object.assign()?

Tags: javascript, object

My main object looks like this:

```
const obj = {

    data: {
        'Puppies' : [],
        'Kittens': []
    }
};
```

I want to assign a value to the data field in data.Puppies[0].

When I try to do this using Object.assign() I get an error:

```
    Unexpected token, expected , (83:12)

  81 | 
  82 |     return Object.assign({}, obj, {
> 83 |         data.Puppies[0]: list
     |             ^
  84 |     });
  85 | }
  86 |
```

I'm not sure how I can accomplish my task.
I need to use Object.assign() because I need to return a new object not the original one. I am doing this because of a Redux reducer in ReactJS.

Comment: so basically cou need to get a copy from obj with an new item in `Puppies` at index zero without mutating the original object, right?

Answer (score 1):

ES6 way without mutations:

```js
const obj = {
    data: {
        'Puppies' : [],
        'Kittens': []
    }
};

const data = Object.assign({}, obj.data, {
                 Puppies: [...obj.data.Puppies, 'newValue']
             });    
const newObject = Object.assign({}, obj, {data});
console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could assign the outer object and assign to the array the new content at index `0` without mutating the original `obj`.

```js
const list = ['foo', 'bar'];
const obj = { data: { Puppies: [], Kittens: [] } };

console.log(Object.assign({}, obj, { data: { Puppies: Object.assign([], obj.data.Puppies, { 0: list }) } }));
console.log(obj);
```

The same with content for `Puppies`.

```js
const list = ['foo', 'bar'];
const obj = { data: { Puppies: ['bar', 42], Kittens: [] } };

console.log(Object.assign({}, obj, { data: { Puppies: Object.assign([], obj.data.Puppies, { 0: list }) } }));
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: What if puppies and kittens might change? How about a variable Kitten?

Comment: then you could use the pattern for `Kitten` as well `{ data: { Kitten: Object.assign([], obj.data.Kitten, { 0: data }) } }`

Comment: NO I mean you have hard-coded Puppies and Kittens. What if we don't know which one it is?

Comment: if you dont know what array you need with some new data, you can not assign it, anyway. for a deep copy, you could use some other technique.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Puppies with a new array with `list` as element 0 and the rest of Puppies starting with element 1, so effectively replacing element 0.

```
var obj = { data: { 'Puppies': [], 'Kittens': [] } };
var list = [ 'a', 'b' ];

var n = Object.assign({}, obj, {
  data: Object.assign({}, obj.data, {
    Puppies: [ list ].concat(obj.data.Puppies.slice(1))
  })
});

console.log(obj);
console.log(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Ramdajs lens to achieve this

```
const obj = {
    data: {
        'Puppies' : [],
        'Kittens': []
    }
};

const list = [1,2,3,4];
const xlens = R.lensPath(['data', 'Puppies'])
console.log(R.set(xlens, list, obj))
```

[Here](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27Puppies%27%20%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27Kittens%27%3A%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20list%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%3B%0Aconst%20xlens%20%3D%20R.lensPath%28%5B%27data%27%2C%20%27Puppies%27%5D%29%0AR.set%28xlens%2C%20list%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A) is the code repel

Comment: ,, you are obsessed by ramda .

Comment: nothing wrong but only editing answers of others and injecting this poor library